# ubuntu 17.04 and -mx32 compilation flag multilib

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, gcc

I have some code that was compiled with the -mx32 flag (compiler and linker) on a previous ubuntu OS amd64.
Actually on ubuntu 17.04 for amd64 compilation ends saying

I cannot find -lncurses

I don't find the way to install the x32 ncurses library, and I am wondering if support is still there.

Comment: did you check out this https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/libx32ncurses5-dev/ ?

Comment: @Mohamad-jaafar It worked, but shouldn't it work by installing a library as libncurses:x32 ( according to the multilib novel approach ) ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert. All the thing that I've faced an almost similar problem before and solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

Please find the application in the online apps directory provided by Ubuntu on the following [link](http://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/libx32ncurses5-dev).